# How to embed commandline arguments in a execution command?

Tags: python, c++, command-line-arguments

I need to pass the commandline arguments of my C++ code as the commandline arguments of my python script.

My code looks like:

```
int main(int argc,char * argv[]) {
FILE *in;
char buff[512];

cout<<argv[1];

string str = "python comparescript.py "+argv[1]+" "+argv[2]+" "+argv[3];

if(!(in = popen(str, "r"))){
    cout<<"Image Comparison made successful";
}
cout<<"Image Comparison made successful";
```

It shows an eror like :

error: invalid operands of types 'const char [25]' and 'char*' to binary 'operator+'

How to append my commandline arguments with the python execution command?

Comment: There is a difference between a `const char[]` and a `std::string`.  The string is a C++ class whereas the `char[]` is an array of primitives.  I would research C++ string to understand more of how to create and manipulate them.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to concatenate strings using the `+` operator, at least one of them needs to be a `std::string` object.

The simplest solution? Just do

```
string str = string("python comparescript.py ")+argv[1]+" "+argv[2]+" "+argv[3];
```

Comment: Thank you ! Adding strdup() and converting them to c string after this solved the problem !

Comment: @KaushikRamachandran What, `strdup`? Converting to C strings? Why? The first may cause memory leaks (remember that `strdup` *allocates* memory), and the second is not needed.